How to use lw or lb to read a char stored in memory?
I am trying to convert a integer to two's compliment binary. When I attempt to read a the ascii value from memory it says my address is out of range. I'm fairly new to MIPS and can't find a way around this or where I am going wrong.
.data   
prompt:     .asciiz "Enter a number: " 
result:     .asciiz "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000"
ng:     .asciiz "Negative"
ps:     .asciiz "Positive"
.text
    # Get input
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, prompt
    syscall
    li  $v0, 5
    syscall
    move    $t0, $v0    # Input = t0
    # Initialization
    la  $t1, result # address of first in array
    addi    $t1, $t1, 38    # address of last in array
    li  $t2, 3      # counter for space = t2
negTest:
    beqz    $t0, exit   # if zero, No conversion needed so print
    
    bltz    $t0, isNeg  # if Negative
    # if Positive
    li  $t3, 1
    
toBin:
    blez    $t0, exit
    andi    $t5, $t0, 1     # t5 = input % 2
    addi    $t5, $t5, 48        # t5 = character
    srl $t0, $t0, 1     # t0 = input / 2
    sb  $t5, ($t1)      # array[i] = t5

    # Increment
    beqz    $t2, skip   # check if looped 4 times
    addi    $t2, $t2, -1    # loop count
    addi    $t1, $t1, -1    # moves to next index
    b   toBin
skip:
    li  $t2, 3
    addi    $t1, $t1, -2    #moves to next index
    b   toBin
    
isNeg:
    li  $t3, -1         # Set $t3 to -1
    mult    $t0, $t3        # Multiply by -1
    mflo    $t0             # Store the hi $t0
    b   toBin

conv:
        # Initialization
        la  $t1, result # address of first in array
        addi    $t1, $t1, 38    # address of last in arrayt2
        li  $t6, 48     # ascii 0
        li  $t7, 49     # ascii 1
        li  $t8, 32     # count for flip
        
flip:
    blez    $t8, addBit
    lb  $t4, ($t1)  # Error Points Here
    beq $t4, $t6, ZerOne    # Flip 0 - 1
    beq $t4, $t7, OneZer    # Flip 1 -0
    addi    $t1, $t1, -2    #moves to next index ignore space
    b   flip
OneZer:
    sb  $t6, ($t1)  # Turn into 0
    addi    $t1, $t1, -1    #moves to next index ignore space
    addi    $t8, $t8, -1    # Count 
    b   flip
    
ZerOne:
    sb  $t7, ($t1)  # Turn into 1
    addi    $t1, $t1, -1    #moves to next index ignore space
    addi    $t8, $t8, -1    # Count
    b   flip
    
addBit:
    la  $t1, result # address of first in array
        addi    $t1, $t1, 38    # address of last in array
        li  $t2, 3          # counter for space = $t2   
    
loop:
    lb  $t4, ($t1)  
    beq $t4, $t6, endC  # if 0 add and end
    sb  $t6, ($t1)
    # Increment
    beqz    $t2, skip2  # check if looped 4 times
    addi    $t2, $t2, -1    # loop count
    addi    $t1, $t1, -1    # moves to next index
    b   loop
skip2:
    li  $t2, 3
    addi    $t1, $t1, -2    # moves to next index
    b   loop
endC:
    addi    $t4, $t4, 1 # turn to 1 ascii
    sb  $t4, ($t1)
    addi    $t3, $t3, 2 # break convert loop
    b   exit        

exit:
    bltz    $t3, conv
    li  $v0, 4
    la  $a0, result
    syscall
    li  $v0, 10
    syscall

I want to read the ascii value to flip from 0 to 1, and 1 to 0. Then add 1 bit to the binary to complete the 2's compliment in the case of a negative number.

Does the first half of the program run correctly? (Converting the value to ASCII?) If so, then you can reduce the problem by removing it from the code and just replace the result with a precalculated result. It is not clear what the second half of the program is trying to do. All you said was "convert a integer to two's compliment binary" but the MIPS is already two's complement. There is nothing to convert.

The first part works however throw the error when converting a negative number. the second part of the code flips and adds a bit.

Use your debugger/simulator to single step the code and see where it goes wrong. Anyway, the error is the addi $t1, $t1, -2 which should of course be -1.  As Raymond said, your input value is already in two's complement, if you do not multiply it by -1 then you don't have to do the conversion at the end at all (the blez $t0, exit should be beqz $t0, exit or better yet just process all 32 bits in case the buffer is not preset to all zeroes).
